# I am looking for a good free domain

Tags: domains, free

I am looking for a good free domain based upon these criteria :
1. No ads.
2. Full DNS management.
3. Free renewal for both personal and business use.
4. No any requirement to maintain the domain name.

Please tell me if you know one.
Thank in advance !

Comment: you might want to check out .tk domains

Comment: @Christofian, .tk has traffic requirement